# Binding an NSTableView to an NSArrayController instead of fetching the data directly from my model array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

### Current Situation: Direct Binding

I have an `NSTableView` which displays the data that comes from an `NSArray` of my custom objects.

### Desired Approach: Array Controller

However, It would be "more best practise" to use an `NSArrayController` instead as a facade to my arbritary model object.

So I duplicated the table in my application and created a new `NSViewController` where I bound the `Table Content` of the `NSTableView` to the `NSArrayController`. I added an `IBOutlet` for this class so I can now setup my View Controller like this:

```
ContactListViewController *myVC = [[ContactListViewController alloc] init];

// Tell the ArrayController where the content-array is.
myVC.contactsArrayController.content = self.myModel.contactsArray;
```

Now since I bound the `Table Content` of the table view to the array controller, I would expect, that as soon as I fill the array with data (from a remote service) that the tableview is updated, which is the case for my other approach where I bind to `myModel.contactsArray` directly.

### The Problem: No data

However, the table remains empty. Do I have to setup something else for this to work (Maybe some `willChangeValueForKey`-magic or something else I have missed. I already tried to set the array controller as the `dataSource` and the `delegate` of the `NSTableView` but that did not seem to work either (Anyway it is not clear to me how `dataSource` and the `Table Content` binding "relate to each other").

Comment: Is this a cell-based table view or view-based table view?

Comment: Sounds like the binding is hooked up correctly, then.

Comment: It's a `NSTableCellView`-based cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill up your array with content, are you re-assigning an immutable array or appending to a mutable array? Either way, it won't work quite how you're expecting.

When you set the content of an array controller this way, instead of keeping a reference, the array controller just copies the content. Subsequent changes will have no effect, whether it's a mutable array (nor if you reassign the model's contactsArray).

Instead:

1. Call `-add:`on the array controller when you insert content. That probably that won't help in your case.
2. If you use immutable arrays you could *bind* the array controller to `myModel`'s `contactsArray` key instead of assigning it.
3. If you use a mutable array I don't think that will work. You could create a second array controller in the model and bound the view's array controller to `contactsArrayController.arrangedObjects`. Maybe there's a better way, but that's what I've done in the past.

Comment: I now try to assign the data like this: `[overlayWC.contactsController addObjects:self.model.channels];` which should not circumvent the mechanism, but I still don't have any data in my table.

Comment: I finally figured it out and could setup the table with an NSArrayController. I have had another issue with my window, not being present, when the data was already ready...