# directory listing in nstableview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I get list of directories in NSTableView?

For example, I have an array with list of directories and IBOutlet for TableView.

What's next?

Comment: Uh, implement the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol, perhaps?

Comment: Its like Beckham raced to the goal post and ball is in the line...and waiting for someone to just push it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should check out this tutorials about `NSTableViews`. The creator of the tutorials is very good. I started learning objective-c by watching his videos.
Take a look at these tutorials:

1. [Tutorial 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Qbjwx0hB6A) - Introduction to `NSTableViews`
2. [Tutorial 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5U94-uRCOo) - Adding data to `NSTableViews`
3. [Tutorial 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Pm1CfmQxfE) - Editing the Data

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an array with a list of directories, you can either implement the  [required NSTableView data source protocol methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

You could also [bind your table view to an array controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164867/binding-an-nstableview-to-an-nsarraycontroller-instead-of-fetching-the-data-dire) which *"owns"* that array with a list of directories.